# Standard Deviation Program

Tags: c

This was the instructions: Write a program that starts out asking the user for the mean u and
standard deviation s for the normal distribution
(see the wiki article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution
The program then asks for an N, and then asks for N values x. For each x it
writes out f(x) to the screen.
Note that the program asks the user for u, s, and N just once. After that it
asks for N values for x, one by one. After each value x it writes out the
corresponding value of the function.
Of course, use double precision for this and use the square root and
exponential function from the standard math library.

This is my code so far but I can't get the N to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.141592653589793238462643383
#define E 2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470937
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
double u,s,N,x,math1, math2, math3,n,;
printf("Enter Mean: \n");
scanf("%d", &u);
printf("Enter Deviation: \n");
scanf("%d", &s);


    n=1/2;
math1 =1/(u*sqrt(2*PI));
math2= (x-u)/s * (x-u)/s;
math3= E * exp(n);
x = math1 * exp(math3)*exp(math2);
printf("%d \n", x);
system("Pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n=1/2;
```

This will be equal to 0, since 1 is an integer, 2 is an integer and 1 divided by 2 is 0 in integer math.

Try `1.0/2.0`

Make sure every other division has a double on one or both sides, otherwise it will be done as integer math